# GraphFrames with pySpark

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, graphframes

I want to use GraphFrames with PySpark (currently using Spark v2.3.3, on Google Dataproc).

After installing GraphFrames with

```
pip install graphframes
```

I try to run the follwing code:

```
from graphframes import *

localVertices = [(1,"A"), (2,"B"), (3, "C")]

localEdges = [(1,2,"love"), (2,1,"hate"), (2,3,"follow")]

v = sqlContext.createDataFrame(localVertices, ["id", "name"])

e = sqlContext.createDataFrame(localEdges, ["src", "dst", "action"])

g = GraphFrame(v, e)
```

but I get this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o301.loadClass.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graphframes.GraphFramePythonAPI
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use GraphFrames with Spark, you should install it as a [Spark package](https://spark-packages.org/package/graphframes/graphframes), not a PIP package:

```sh
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.3-s_2.11
```

Comment: I have passed that as an env variable in my Dockerfile `ENV PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12"` but I do still get the error:   `File "/usr/local/spark/jobs/cetus/graph_post_processor_job.py", line 7, in <module>
    from graphframes import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphframes'`.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Jupyter for development start it from pyspark and not directly or from Anaconda. Meaning open the terminal and then run

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.6.0-spark2.3-s_2.11
```

This starts Jupyter with the correct PySpark packages loaded in the background. If you then import it in your script with `from graphframes import` it will pick it up correctly and run