# graphframes for pySpark v3.0.1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, graphframes

I'm trying to use the **graphframes** library with **pySpark** v3.0.1. (I'm using vscode on debian but trying to import the package from pyspark shell didn't work either)

According to the [documentation](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/quick-start.html), using `$ pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.6.0-spark2.3-s_2.11` I should be able to work with it.

This sample code was taken from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068469/graphframes-with-pyspark) in StackOverflow posing the same question, although its solution didn't do the trick for me.

```python
localVertices = [(1,"A"), (2,"B"), (3, "C")]

localEdges = [(1,2,"love"), (2,1,"hate"), (2,3,"follow")]

v = sqlContext.createDataFrame(localVertices, ["id", "name"])

e = sqlContext.createDataFrame(localEdges, ["src", "dst", "action"])

g = GraphFrame(v, e)
```

throws error

```python
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o63.createGraph.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps scala.Predef$.refArrayOps(java.lang.Object[])'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct graphframes version for Spark 3.0. You have used the graphframes for Spark 2.3 (0.6.0-**spark2.3**-s_2.11), which caused a Spark version conflict. You can try 0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12, which is currently the latest version of graphframes for Spark 3.0.

```
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12
```

Comment: works in pyspark shell.  I'm having trouble using it from vscode. I'm going to look into it thanks!

Comment: @VectorXY you might need to download a graphframes jar and put it in $SPARK_HOME/jars

Comment: yeap that worked... i was trying to run the shell script above from inside the editor! Thanks again!